# Highlight label and change color in span if checkbox is checked

Tags: html, css, checkbox, label, checked

If **checkbox** is checked, I need to highlight **label**. And change color of **span** in this **label**.
Label is working fine, but I don't know, how to change color of span, when checkbox is checked.

HTML

```
<input class="check" type="radio" name="typeSelect" id="a" value="1" /><label class="labelcheck" for="a"> <span >Hello </span> World</label>
<input class="check" type="radio" name="typeSelect" id="b" value="2" /><label class="labelcheck" for="b"> <span >Hi </span> Again</label>
```

CSS

```
.check:checked + .labelcheck {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.check:checked + .labelcheck + . span {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the span is a child of label, you can just do:

```
.check:checked + .labelcheck {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.check:checked + .labelcheck span {
    color: red;
}
```